# Can I get additional ElasticSearch index settings?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, plainelastic.net

To optimize bulk insertions of a large amount of data into ElasticSearch indexes, I'm adding functionality to our driver to suspend index refreshes for a period of time. I've done this using [admin indices update settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/) to set `index.refresh_interval` to -1 and the back to 1 second. However, I can't seem to find a way to get `index.refresh_interval` back from ElasticSearch, which means I can't get it to restore it later, can't do consistency checks against the index, and can't really test that what I've done has actually worked.

I've tried:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/[index_name]/_settings/
```

..but the result had only contained three settings, which seemed too few. Perhaps this REST call can take additional parameters to get more/different settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution before I posted the question, but as I'd already typed the question out, I thought I'd post it and the answer.

Basically, that `GET` call against the `_settings` endpoint in the question is what you need. *However*, if `index.refresh_interval` hasn't been set on the index beforehand, either when created or through the `_settings` endpoint, it doesn't appear in the list of settings returned. It seems like ElasticSearch doesn't hold a value for the setting for its default (which is 1 second, "1s").

I assume that ES only returns settings that don't have defaults or have been changed from their default, for brevity. It's a little confusing to begin with though, especially as the documentation for [admin indices get settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-settings/) is a bit... brief.